# Автоматическое обновление дизайнера WPF Visual Studio 2022

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Перешёл с VS 2019 на VS 2022 и заметил, что для того, чтобы изменения в XAML разметке отобразились в дизайнере, его необходимо обновить кнопкой "Обновить":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот простой пример, XAML разметка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизайнер до нажатия кнопки обновить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизайнер после нажатия кнопки обновить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никогда такого не замечал в 19 версии студии, мб что-то надо выбрать в настройках, чтобы дизайнер самостоятельно обновлялся?